# Thread usage counter C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

In a C++ class, How can I limit the number calls/uses of a certain function for each thread?
For example, each thread is allowed only to use a certain data setter for 3 times.

Comment: You mean, one thread can only use a setter 3 times in total? Or do you mean the setter can be used by (up to) 3 threads simultanously?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes I mean one thread can only use a setter 3 times in total.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification :)

Comment: what did you try? how did it fail? What should happen when the method is called the 4th time?

Comment: I honestly do not how to implement it. I researched and couldn't find much. In the 4th time, it should get blocked from using it and safely fail.

Comment: What would you like to have happen when you call/use the function the 4th time?  Throw an exception?  Block?  Terminate?  Display an error?  Why does it matter which thread is calling it?  What are you actually trying to accomplish?  A `thread_local` counter and a `mutex` (or atomic/interlocked increment) should do it. See the [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to count how often the method has been called for each thread and then react accordingly:

```
void Foo::set(int x) {
    static std::map<std::thread::id,unsigned> counter;
    auto counts = ++counter[std::this_thread::get_id()];
    if (counts > max_counts) return;

    x_member = x;
}
```

This is just to outline the basic idea. I am not so sure about the `static` map. I am not even sure if it is a good idea to let the method itself implement the counter. I would rather put this elsewhere, eg each thread could get a `CountedFoo` instance that holds a reference to the actual `Foo` object and the `CountedFoo` controls the maximum number of calls.

PS: And of course, don't forget to use some synchronisation when multiple threads are calling the method concurrently (for the sake of brevity I did not include any mutex or similar in the above code).

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::map` to store thread Ids as sugested by @formerlyknownas_463035818 would probably be the most robust solution, but synchronization might prove more complex.

The fastest solution to this issue is using `thread_local`. This will enable each thread to have its own copy of the counter. Here is the working example which might prove useful.

```
thread_local unsigned int N_Calls = 0;
std::mutex mtx;

void controlledIncreese(const std::string& thread_name){
    while (N_Calls < 3) {
        ++N_Calls;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(rand() % 2));

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);      
        std::cout << "Call for thread " << thread_name.c_str() << ": " << N_Calls << '\n';
    }       
}

int main(){
    std::thread first_t(controlledIncreese, "first"), second_t(controlledIncreese, "second");
    first_t.join();
    second_t.join();
}
```

Since both Threads are using `std::cout` the actual output will be sequential, so this specific example is not very useful but it does provide easy working solution to thread execution counting problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. when I add  ' thread_local int counter_ = 0; ' to the private section of my class, it gives me an error. storage class specified for counter 'counter_' Can you help me with that please?

Comment: If you need to reduce the scope you can make it static. 
I would strongly recommend reading this article:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration